# sending parameter to the controller function failed

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my first codeigniter project and I am getting some errors.

I tried to send parameters to the controller function with the following code. But it shows error in controller file that `'Missing arguement 1 for school::add_topic'`

Here is my code:-view file- I have only included the important parts of the code

```
<?php
$createdby='';
?>
<a class="admin-btn" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/school/add_topic/<?php echo myfunction(); ?>">Add Topic</a>
<?php
foreach ($r as $new)
{
    ?>
    <?php 
    if($new->id_class==$class && $new->id_subject==$sub)
    {
        $createdby=$new->id_login;
        ?>
        <tr><th>Class</th><td> <?php echo $new->class_name; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><th>Subject</th><td>
        <?php echo $new->subject_name; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><th>Created By</th><td>
        <?php echo $new->staff_name; ?></td>
        <th>Created On</th><td>
        <?php echo $new->created_on; ?></td></tr>


    <?php
    }
}
function myfunction()
{
global $createdby;
return $createdby;
}
?>
```

What I want to do is to send the variable `'$createdby'` to my controller function `'add_topic()'`.

This is my controller function:

```
public function add_topic($createdby)
{
    $data['createdby'] = $createdby;
    $this->load->view('topic_add',$data);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`index.php/school/add_topic/` is just the call of the function `add_topic` of the controller `school`, but there is no parameter, so the function does not get anything. Add a parameter after the slash (e.g. `index.php/school/add_topic/xyz`) and `$createdby` will be xyz.

Additionally, you may use the function [`site_url()`](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) of the URL Helper instead of writing `index.php/xxxxx`

```
site_url('school/add_topic/param');
```

In your example, you got a very complex structure - why not use it like this:

```
<a class="admin-btn" href="<?=site_url('school/add_topic/'.$createdby)?>">Add Topic</a>
```

Another hint you may see: `<?php echo $xyz; ?>` can be written `<?=$xyz?>` while `=` being the echo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used the parameter after school/add_topic/  that is "<?php echo myfunction(); ?>". I get a value for $createdby later in the code(inside the foreach ) so I think I cannot directly add $createdby. So I used the function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code flow is incorrect such that the $createdby is been called before it get initialized. You can try this code:

```
<?php
$createdby='';
$selected = '';
if (!empty($r)) {
    foreach ($r as $new)
    {
        if($new->id_class==$class && $new->id_subject==$sub)
        {
            $createdby=$new->id_login;
            $selected = $new;
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
<a class="admin-btn" href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/school/add_topic/'. myfunction(); ?>">Add Topic</a>
<?php
if (!empty($selected)) {
    ?>
        <tr><th>Class</th><td> <?php echo $selected->class_name; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><th>Subject</th><td>
        <?php echo $selected->subject_name; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><th>Created By</th><td>
        <?php echo $selected->staff_name; ?></td>
        <th>Created On</th><td>
        <?php echo $selected->created_on; ?></td></tr> <?php
}

function myfunction()
{
global $createdby;
return $createdby;
}
?>
```

And also there can be a chance of $createdby is not initialized, so the controller function should have an optional parameter than a fixed one.

```
public function add_topic($createdby = '')
{
    $data['createdby'] = $createdby;
    $this->load->view('topic_add',$data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  The second solution easily solved that error. (public function add_topic($createdby = ' ')

Comment: The error is not showing now. But  '$createdby'  is not passing anything  to the view  'topic_add' .

Comment: Check whether $createdby is set or not before passing